# Rearrange a class structure for better performance

Tags: c#, class, oop

I have a class relation ship like below,

```
public class CollegeInfo
{
    public int CollegeId { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<int, DepartementInfo> DepartementInfo { get; set; }
}

public class DepartementInfo
{
    public int CollegeId { get; set; }
    public int DepartementId { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<int, DataGridViewRowInfo> DataGridViewRowsInfo { get; set; }
}

public struct DataGridViewRowInfo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public int CollegeId { get; set; }
    public int RowID;
    public int DepartementId ;

    public string SpecialString { get; set; }        
}
```

If I have a object of `CollegeInfo`, I will be having different `DepartementInfoand` in each frame will have a collection of `DataGridViewRowInfo`

You all can see that we have `CollegeId` in all class and `DepartementId` in two classes how can I rearrange these classed to make a better relation, If I take a single object of `DataGridViewRowInfo` it should have corresponding `CollegeId` and `DepartementId`?

I have done a modification in the class structure , Please let me know the first one or this one is better

```
   public class CollegeInfo
   {  
      public Dictionary<int, DepartementInfo> DepartementInfo { get; set; }
   }

   public class DepartementInfo
   {
      public Dictionary<int, DataGridViewRowInfo> DataGridViewRowsInfo { get; set;}
   }

   public class DataGridViewRowInfo
   {
      public string Id { get; set; }
      public int CollegeId { get; set; }
      public int RowID;
      public int DepartementId ;
      public string SpecialString { get; set; }        
   }
```

I will keep data only in `DataGridViewRowInfo`, Most probably I will be having at least one department and inside that one or more `DataGridViewRowInfo` so if I need to get detail of a specific object, for example `DepartementInfo` I could get it from its property. But whether it is a good practice ?

Comment: Does the DataGridViewRowInfo actually need to have the IDs of its associated CollegeInfo and DepartementInfo classes, or can you just infer this at runtime from whatever collection in which you're storing them?

Comment: I need to take DataGridViewRowInfo  object some time ( for search eg) that time I need to check which is the department and which is the College , so I prefer to have that details

Comment: Then the only option is either what you have done, which is to store the ID of the other objects, or store references to the objects themselves, i.e. rather than `int CollegeId` have `CollegeInfo CollegeId`.  You can even make it a requirement in your constructor that a CollegeId and DepartementInfo are provided at creation time.

Comment: Ok @LordWilmore I think your idea is better, And I have one more Idea and I will post as answer,

Comment: might be a valid candidate for CodeReview :)

Comment: this looks awful.  I'm not quite sure what problem you want to solve, but, by the looks of it,  a College as many Departments, Departments has many whatever a DGVRI is

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is better in performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39263186/which-is-better-in-performance)