# Which is better in performance?

Tags: c#, oop

I have 1000000 data which has some relation or can be group in to 3 groups. 
I will be have random update and add into these data.
Also I may need to search many time with some property value.

This is the class structure

```
public struct DataGridViewRowInfo
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public int CollegeId { get; set; }
   public int RowID;
   public int DepartementId ;
   public string SpecialString { get; set; }       
}
```

I have following 3 idea to keep it. I would like to know which could be better.

> 1. Keep as a single list of above object
> 2. In a hierarchical structure

```
public class CollegeInfo
{
    public int CollegeId { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, DepartementInfo> DepartementInfo { get; set; }
}

public class DepartementInfo
{
   public int CollegeId { get; set; }
   public int DepartementId { get; set; }
   public Dictionary<int, DataGridViewRowInfo> DataGridViewRowsInfo { get; set;      }
}

 public struct DataGridViewRowInfo
 {
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public int CollegeId { get; set; }
   public int RowID;
   public int DepartementId ;
   public string SpecialString { get; set; }        
}
```

> or 3. keep data in a file and operate on a small group of data.

Comment: If you want to find out which of two horses is fastest, race them

Comment: @DavidPilkington Ahh yes, the good old [horse race](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)